# Connection to website uptobox.com with cookie

Tags: python

how to register on a website using cookies with the request library.
using the code below I can not connect.

```
import requests
cookie = {
 "name": "xfss",
 "value": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "domain": ".uptobox.com",
 "hostOnly": "",
 "path": "/",
 "secure": "",
 "httpOnly": "",
 "session": "",
 "expirationDate": '1553281395',
 "storeId": "firefox-private",
 "firstPartyDomain": ""
 }
 r = requests.post("https://uptobox.com/?op=login&referer=homepage",cookies=cookie)
 print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works:

```
import urllib2,urllib

UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de-DE; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : UA }

url = 'https://uptobox.com/'
post_data = {}
post_data['op'] = 'login'
post_data['login'] = 'LOGIN'
post_data['password'] = 'MDP'

req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(post_data), headers)
req.add_header('cookie', 'xfss=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print "debug" + str(getattr(e, "code", None))
    print "debug" + str(getattr(e, "reason", None))

sHtmlContent = response.read()
head = response.headers
cookies=response.info()['Set-Cookie']
response.close()

print cookies
print head
print 'Connected ' + str('op=my_account' in sHtmlContent)
```

But I have a question for you: How do you get the xfss cookie dynamically ? I think it expires every 24 hours